# How do I check if my phone has hardware video encoder?

Tags: samsung, video, gpu, cpu, hardware-acceleration

I own a Samsung j7 2016 and I did some search about the CPU and looked for information tools but I've found codec info but not hardware video encoder info anywhere.

If you know any app or adb command to retrieve info about this, it'll be helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36887469/how-to-do-hardware-h-264-video-encoding-on-android-platform

Comment: [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.tyniw.mediacodecinfo.application) gives you information on codecs on your device. I am not sure if *hardware* encoder information is contained. You can check and let me know